# Connecting physical tensors to mathematical tensors

Tags: category-theory, tensors, monoidal-categories

I feel like I (maybe) understand the mathematical /algebraic perspective on tensors, for example as described in [Wikipedia/Monoidal Category](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category). You need a (simultaneously left & right) unit and an associative bilinear functor which gets called $\otimes$ -- its associative commutating can be expressed by "the" pentagon if so desired.

But then if I look at [Wikipedia/Tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tensor), all the simplicity goes away. Suddenly I have to deal with coordinates; there are a lot of subscripts flying around; and all of this somehow relates to stress & strain, particularly (maybe) in fluids.

Can someone help me make the connection to e.g. [this description](http://www.whoi.edu/fileserver.do?id=25330&pt=2&p=30169)? How do you get from a tangle of $\partial \over \partial_I$'s back to the simplicity of the braided monoidal category?

Comment: one thing that helped me to understand the relation between these two object was: Physicists leads with the trace, with the coordinates, not with the basis. For them this is implicit over the index-convention.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi when I hear "trace" I think "counit". Is this in line with your thoughts?

Comment: Your approach is the same! But in fact, it is!

Comment: Does §7 of Keith Conrad's *Tensor Products I* ( http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf ) help? (Also keep in mind that physicists' "tensors" are mathematicians' "tensor fields", which are more complicated than tensors by design. A mathematician's "tensor" is probably what a physicist would call "tensor at a point", or something like that.)